# Insert delayed when network error and insert trigger inserting on dblink-table

Tags: oracle

Maybe a strange title, I'll try to explain.
I have two Oracle servers serverA and serverB.

- On serverA I have a table tabA in which every minute a row is
  inserted.
- On serverB I create a table tabB that has the same
  structure as tabA.
- On serverA I create a dblink to serverB. On
  serverA I create a insert trigger like

On A

```
create trigger tabA_trig
after insert on tabA
begin
insert into tabB@serverB(...) values(:new....,:new... etc);

exception
 when others then null;
end tabA_trig;
```

After the creation of this trigger a new row is inserted into tabB every time a new row is inserted into tabA, as expected.

HOWEVER: when the communication between serverA and serverB is broken, I don't get any errors (the exception above takes care of that), BUT no data is inserted into tabA either! Very strange, and what is even stranger is that after about 15 minutes, new data gets inserted into tabA again. After a while the missing data starts to fill in the hole and after a while no data is missing and the insert functions as expected.

Example (tabA and tabB, first column time minutes and hours, second column value):

```
Network OK:
tabA 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22
tabB 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22    

Network ERROR:
About 15 minutes of no new data.

After 15 minutes:
tabA 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22;1017 22;1018 22;....
tabB 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22


After 30 minutes:
tabA 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22;1003 22;1004 22;1005 22;1006 22;1017 22;1018 22;....
tabB 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22

After 1 hour:
tabA 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22;1003 22;1004 22;1005 22;1006 22;1006 22;...;1017 22;1018 22;....
tabB 1000 22;1001 22;1002 22
```

If I disable the trigger, the insert on tabA works immediately.

The reason I'm using triggers and not materialized views is that I want to keep all data that has been replicated to tabB even when data is deleted from tabA.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

Answer (score 1):

First, replicating data from one database to another using custom triggers is almost certainly a bad idea.  Oracle provides a variety of technologies that help you implement replication.  Materialized views are probably the simplest and most likely what you'd want here though you could also look at Streams or Golden Gate or even something like Change Data Capture (CDC).  Custom triggers have a substantial impact on the performance of the triggering insert and they introduce a variety of failure scenarios such as this that are hard to debug.

Since no data is being inserted into `tabA` while the network is down but those inserts are appearing later, I would tend to suspect that some sort of exception is being raised that causes the inserting application to either queue the insert until later or that the application is creating a distributed transaction that involves either database B or some other resource that is also affected by the network error that cannot be successfully committed until some later point in time.  Since we don't know anything about your application's architecture, it's hard to speculate too deeply.  You can check the `DBA_2PC_PENDING` table to see if Oracle is acting as the distributed transaction coordinator for any distributed transactions but there are numerous other software components that might be acting as the transaction coordinator.

Answer (score 1):

Or Oracle advanced queues if both database are similar versions.  A little tricky to set up but the asynchronous messaging model will handle instances where one database or another is down.

As to whether it is too complex a solution I find that I simplify the questions I put here. What the entire problem is only the OP can tell. Does the problem seem like more of a messaging problem or amalgamating data?  Both solutions will work much better than triggers.

Comment: AQ is an overkill. A Fast Refresh MV was made excatly for his needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to activate dead connection detection using
   [SQLNET.EXPIRETIME](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aNet_FAQ#How_does_one_enable_dead_connection_detection.3F%20%22SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME)
2. I wouldn't recommend replication the way you are doing it. You can use an "ON COMMIT REFRESH" materialized view to achieve this kind of replication.

Comment: SQLNET.EXPIRETIME only works on the serverside. I'm not sure I can use materialized views for my solution (only inserts shall be propagated to tabB).